# Why did System Restore wipe out a complete desktop, and a lot of files on the primary partition?

Tags: system-restore, wipe, windows-7-restore

The PC was running unusually slow so I thought I'd restore it to a few days back and see what happens. I put up system restore point to 2 days ago, that's 11th of May.
And when I loaded Windows again and logged in, here's what happened:

- My desktop was completely wiped out.
- I am unable to view hidden files or folders, or enable this option (folder options advanced settings went blank).
- Most of my documents on C drive went missing, but all programs are still installed and drive D is intact.
- Some drivers behave strangely, mousewheel on mouse won't work.

[image]

Nothing actually went wrong during the restoration process.
Is this a common issue that can easily be resolved?

Comment: Its really hard to say its clearly not normal so it has to be the restoration point itself or the an effect of the reason you even used it in the first place

Comment: The PC was running unusually slow so I thought I'd restore it  to a few days back and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked:

I uninstalled AVG antivirus, then restored to a few days further back.

Surprisingly, everything was the way it was. AVG was causing problems.

Comment: You might want to use [AVG Remover](http://www.avg.com/eu-en/utilities) to delete any leftovers.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like more of an effect of a malware infestation. I'd be tempted to wipe and reinstall to avoid all the aggro, however there are steps you could take if you'd like to attempt to recover the system.

**Things to try**

- Try to restore to a different restore point.
- Create a brand new user account, login with that and see if the problem persists
- Open an elevated command prompt and typing `chkdsk c: /f` and reboot to check the disk for errors (do this before any further steps).
- Open an elevated command prompt and typing `sfc /scannow`

Good luck, I'll post some more suggestions if these don't work for you.

### Desktop & Documents

Check for the existence to the path to your desktop. The Desktop and Documents path defaults to `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\`. If your desktop files are there then you need to change your desktop path.

**Changing your Desktop/Documents Path**

1. Click on "Start" and type `regedit`.
2. Right click on `regedit` in the start menu and click on `Run as Administrator`.
3. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders` and update your path for Desktop/Documents value there.
4. Repeat step 3 but for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`.
5. Logout and back in.

### Folder Options

Just found a blog entry that describes the problem you were having with the folder options window. I checked the file and it looks clean, look for the "7" download like on [this page](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/restore-corrupted-folder-options-advanced-settings-caused-by-virus/) or you could download the .reg file [directly](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=1598).